# How do I run unit tests from smaller applications inside of a parent directory?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

I'm working in a repository with multiple smaller applications for various lambdas.  I'd like to be able to run `cargo test` from the top level directory, but I can't seem to find a way to get this to work since the files aren't nested within a top level `src` directory.

```
├── cloudformation
├── apps
│   ├── app1
│   │   └── src
│   └── app2
│       └── src
└── otherStuff
```

Ideally I could run `cargo test` from the top level and it would dig into apps and run tests from the `src` directory nested within each individual app.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html

Comment: `find -name Cargo.toml -exec ...` ?

Comment: This definitely works, thanks!  `find . -type f -name Cargo.toml -execdir cargo test \;`